# Shell script to read variables from file and use that in perl script

Tags: bash, shell

I want to write a shell script, that reads a file and use the columns of that file as input for a perl script. The perl script is going through files (number1, number2), pulls out the ID and write those to a new file. The perl script is working fine if I use it with the command line, however, my question is how I write a shell script to use the variables in my input_file for the perl script.

My input_file looks like

```
number1 ID1
number2 ID2
```

And I use the following shell script (which is not working, so please help with this)

```
#!/bin/bash

input_file="$1" 

while IFS=" " read -r number ID
do
    perl extract.pl $ID $number.ext > $number_ID.ext
done < "$1"
```

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Great site, I did not know it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
$number_ID.ext
```

with

```
${number}_ID.ext
```

`_` is a character allowed in variable names. That's why bash is looking for `$number_ID`. `.` is not allowed.

Comment: Maybe also point out (like http://shellcheck.net/ already does) that  `input_file` is assigned but unused.